# C - Assignment makes pointer from Integer without a cast

Tags: c, string

Just creating a simple cipher program in C. Beginner programmer but am having trouble with strings etc. Anyway, here is the program please tell me if you can help. Error given by the compiler is as stated in the title.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Compile this program with:
//      cc -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o rot rot.c

#define ROT 3

//  The rotate function returns the character ROT positions further along the
//  alphabetic character sequence from c, or c if c is not lower-case

char rotate(char c)
{
    // Check if c is lower-case or not
    if (islower(c))
    {
            // The ciphered character is ROT positions beyond c,
            // allowing for wrap-around
            return ('a' + (c - 'a' + ROT) % 26);
    }
    else
    {
            return c;
    }
}

//  Execution of the whole program begins at the main function

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Exit with an error if the number of arguments (including
    // the name of the executable) is not precisely 2
    if(argc != 2)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: program expected 1 argument, but instead received %d\n", argv[0], argc-1);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
            // Calculate the length of the first argument
            int length = strlen(argv[1]);

            //Convert every character to lowercase characters

            for(int i=0 ; argv[i] ; i++){
                char letternumber = 0;

                argv[1][i] = letternumber;
                argv[1][i] = tolower(letternumber);
            }


            // Loop for every character in the text
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                    // Determine and print the ciphered character
                    printf("%c", rotate(argv[1][i]));
                    printf(" ");
                    printf("%c", argv[1][i]);
                    printf(" ");
                    printf("%d", i);
                    printf("\n");

            }

            // Print one final new-line character
            printf("\n");

            // Exit indicating success
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: so, i also modified the code as well a tiny bit more. As suggested by Bob. However,i still have a problem that the first two letters output just disappear. Please do help why this happens and please do excuse me if my questions are utterly stupid.

Comment: char letternumber seems to be non-initialized?

Comment: What value does `letternumber` has ?

Comment: The compiler told you pretty clearly: `argv` is a `char**`, so `argv[1]`, if it exists, is a `char *`, not a `char`.

Comment: And main question: at which line do you get the error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The error message also tells you the line number where the error occurred

Comment: Please edit question with your new code that is still having a few problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just respond to modified question, since other points have been touched upon; just know that reading unitialized variables like you do 
(`argv[1][i] = letternumber`) is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

```
    // Calculate the length of the first argument
    int length = strlen(argv[1]);

    // Loop for every character in the text
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
            // Determine and print the ciphered character
            printf("%c", rotate(tolower(argv[1][i])));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be here:

```
        for(int i=0 ; argv[i] ; i++){
            char letternumber;

            argv[i] = letternumber;
            argv[i] = tolower(letternumber);
        }
```

You're assigning `letternumber`, a character, to `argv[i]`, a pointer-to-character (`char *`). It appears you're missing a subscript level here, or perhaps you meant something like:

```
            argv[1][i] = letternumber;
```

based on your line which says

```
            int length = strlen(argv[1]);
```

In addition, `letternumber` is never initialized. I suspect that you wanted your cipher block to read something like

```
        for(int i=0 ; argv[1][i] ; i++){
            char letternumber;

            letternumber = argv[1][i];
            argv[1][i] = tolower(letternumber);
        }
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thankyou Bob, that makes alot more sense.

Comment: The temp variable `letternumber` is not really needed. You could just write `argv[1][i] = tolower(argv[1][i]);` and dispense with the temp variable altogether. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, removed the variable and it works. now i am gonna try to understand why it works. haha, Thanks anyway.